# Okada character table for n=6

Tags: co.combinatorics, rt.representation-theory

Order the 13 fibonacci words $v$ of length $|v|=6$ as follows:

\begin{equation}
\begin{array}{ll}
1 &222 \\
2 &2211 \\
3 &2121 \\
4 &2112 \\
5 &2111 \\
6 &1221 \\
7 &1212 \\
8 &12111 \\
9 &1122 \\
10 &11211 \\
11 &11121 \\
12 &11112 \\
13 &111111
\end{array}
\end{equation}

Is it the case that the character table for the Okada algebra $\mathcal{F}_6$ is

\begin{equation}
\begin{array}{r|ccccccccccccc}
222    &-1 &1 &0 &1 &-1 &0 &0 &0 &1 &-1 &0 &-1 &1 \\ \\
2211   &1 &1 &-2 &-1 &-1 &0 &0 &0 &-1 &-1 &2 &1 &1 \\ \\
2121   &0 &0 &1 &-1 &-1 &-1 &1 &1 &0 &0 &-1 &1 &1 \\ \\
2112   &1 &-1 &0 &1 &-1 &0 &-2 &2 &-1 &1 &0 &-1 &1 \\ \\
21111  &-3 &-3 &-2 &-1 &-1 &8 &4 &4 &3 &3 &2 &1 &1 \\ \\
1221   &0 &0 &0 &0 &0 &1 &-1 &-1 &0 &0 &-1 &1 &1 \\ \\
1212   &0 &0 &0 &0 &0 &0 &1 &-1 &-1 &1 &0 &-1 &1 \\ \\
12111  &0 &0 &0 &0 &0 &-2 &-1 &-1 &3 &3 &2 &1 &1 \\ \\
1122   &1 &-1 &0 &-1 &1 &0 &0 &0 &1 &-1 &0 &-1 &1 \\ \\
11211  &-1 &-1 &2 &1 &1 &0 &0 &0 &-1 &-1 &2 &1 &1 \\ \\
11121  &0 &0 &-2 &2 &2 &-1 &1 &1 &0 &0 &-1 &1 &1 \\ \\
11112  &-3 &3 &0 &-3 &3 &0 &-2 &2 &-1 &1 &0 &-1 &1 \\ \\
111111 &15 &15 &10 &5 &5 &8 &4 &4 &3 &3 &2 &1 &1
\end{array}
\end{equation}

Apologies for this tedious, technical question.

*thank you, ines.*

Comment: Perhaps, rather than asking everyone to do this computation and compare the result to yours, you could explain how you got this table, and someone can indicate whether your methods were valid.

Comment: I was hoping that someone might already have done this computation and might just check the records so to speaks. I'm certainly not asking *everyone* to do this computation, let alone you.